# Loop to an object in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Btw, I am new to Typescript and Angular2.

I have a service that returns an object of type **PracticeTestList**.  The declaration of the service and the object is shown below.

Now, I have a custom pipe that reads the object, as shown below.

The custom pipe class did received the object but in **for** loop the object is read as a **single line** string not as an object. Why is that?

How to read the object as an object then in Typescript?

Thanks

**Service**

```
getMyPracticeTest(uid: string){
   return this._http.get('http://localhost:49753/RestServiceImpl.svc/getMyPracticeTest/' + uid)
    .map(data => {
        data.json();
        // the console.log(...) line prevents your code from working 
        // either remove it or add the line below (return ...)
        console.log("getMyPracticeTest >>>>>>> ", <PracticeTestList[]>data.json());
        return <PracticeTestList[]>data.json();
    });
}
```

**Object declaration**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export interface PracticeTestList {
    Purchase_ID: number;
    User_FK: number;
    name: string;
    price: number;
    resteurant: string;
    credit_card_number: string;
    purchase_date : any;
    Test_Status_FK: number;
    child :string;
}
```

**Custom Pipe**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'values'})
export class ValuesPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
        let keys = [];

        for (let key in value) {
            console.log("Key >>>> " + key + "   value >>>>> " + value[key]);
            keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
        }

        return keys;
    }
}
```

**Added Log inside pipe**

```
Key >>>> 0   value >>>>> [  main.bundle.js:64502:13
Key >>>> 1   value >>>>> {  main.bundle.js:64502:13
Key >>>> 2   value >>>>> "  main.bundle.js:64502:13
Key >>>> 3   value >>>>> P  main.bundle.js:64502:13
Key >>>> 4   value >>>>> u  main.bundle.js:64502:13
Key >>>> 5   value >>>>> r  main.bundle.js:64502:13
Key >>>> 6   value >>>>> c  main.bundle.js:64502:13
Key >>>> 7   value >>>>> h  main.bundle.js:64502:13
Key >>>> 8   value >>>>> a  main.bundle.js:64502:13
Key >>>> 9   value >>>>> s  main.bundle.js:64502:13
Key >>>> 10   value >>>>> e  main.bundle.js:64502:13
Key >>>> 11   value >>>>> _  main.bundle.js:64502:13
Key >>>> 12   value >>>>> I  main.bundle.js:64502:13
Key >>>> 13   value >>>>> D  main.bundle.js:64502:13
Key >>>> 14   value >>>>> "  main.bundle.js:64502:13
Key >>>> 15   value >>>>> :  main.bundle.js:64502:13
Key >>>> 16   value >>>>> 1  main.bundle.js:64502:13
Key >>>> 17   value >>>>> ,  main.bundle.js:64502:13
Key >>>> 18   value >>>>> "
```

**Added HTML code**

```
<table class="table" *ngIf="myPurchaseItems">
    <tr *ngFor="let entry  of myPurchaseItems | values">
      <td>Key: {{entry.key}}, value: {{entry.value}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: does it say [Object object] or something similar?

Comment: can you provide a log of what console.log(value) is inside your pipe?

Comment: Can you please post source of your template?

Comment: added logs inside pipes

Comment: added code from the template. - Volodymyr Bilyachat

Comment: @wal yes problme is that you map is not working. I have updated my code

Comment: Can you please post method from your component because i dont understand now..?

Comment: Also in map you have console.log can you add screen what its printing?

Comment: the mapping works fine. the only problem is that the value which is in JSON format is read as a STRING in my custom pipes.

Answer (score 5):

Use `Object.keys` to get the keys first:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({ name: 'values' })
export class ValuesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value): any {
    let keys = Object.keys(value);
    return keys.map(k => value[k]);
  }
}
```

You can try [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the values directly but it might not yet be supported everywhere.